# Error in Changing from nodeList to Array in forEach method

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

I have tried my best to convert my **nodeList** to an **Array** using different methods but it still gives this error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property `'display'` of undefined
at `Project.js:68`
at `Array.forEach` ()
at `HTMLSelectElement.filterTodo`**

I really need a solution or better still, a correction if I'm doing something wrong

```
function filterTodo(e) {
    const todos = Array.from(todoList.childNodes);
    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
        switch (e.target.value){
            case 'all':
            todo.style.display ='flex';
            break;
        case 'completed':
            if (todo.classList.contains('completed')) {
                todo.style.display ='flex';
            } else {
                todo.style.display ='none';
            }
        }
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`todoList.childNodes` will also include non-element nodes like text and comment. These non-element nodes do not have a `style` property, and when you will try to manipulate these by doing `todo.style.display`, it will rightfully throw this error

> Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

To get a collection of only the element nodes, use `todoList.children` instead.

(Also, there is no issue in the nodeList to an Array conversion. It is fine)